# ¿Como se traduciría al español "crunch time"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

En ingles existe la palabra "[crunch time](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crunch_time)":

> A critical period of time during which it is necessary to work hard
>   and fast.
>
> Un periodo crítico de tiempo en el que es necesario trabajar duro y
>   rápido.

¿Qué palabra existe en el español con esa definición?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest I can think of are **"momento/tiempo decisivo/crítico"** & **"hora de la verdad"**

Source: search on multiple webpages including [this one](http://www.linguee.es/ingles-espanol/traduccion/crunch+time.html), own experience, etc.

Comment: Obtenido de [aquí](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=534252)? Si es así, por favor añáde la fuente de tu respuesta.
Obtained from [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=534252)? If so, please add the source to your answer.

Comment: Vease también la discusión bajo "la hora de los loros" aunque esta frase parece ser un localismo peruano.